# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Tezos has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Simon McLoughlin]

[image: ktorn]

[image: utdrmac]

Please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5097986244739072).

Comment: thanks for organising this.